# Meteor - Cannot find module ReactComponentHookTree

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-react

I just created a new app with meteor using `meteor start`. I am trying to follow the [official tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components) to integrate meteor with react but getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook'
```

The app compiles fine, I am getting this in the browser console there are no error while compiling.

Following is the stack trace:

```
modules-runtime.js?hash=e35fc9c…:124Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook'
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=e35fc9c…:124)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.react-dom.lib.ReactDebugTool.js (modules.js?hash=20baf54…:9920)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=e35fc9c…:198)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=e35fc9c…:121)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.react-dom.lib.ReactInstrumentation.js (modules.js?hash=20baf54…:9890)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=e35fc9c…:198)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=e35fc9c…:121)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.react-dom.lib.ReactReconciler.js (modules.js?hash=20baf54…:9507)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=e35fc9c…:198)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=e35fc9c…:121)
```

Comment: What does stack trace say?

Comment: @imkost I have added stack trace to the question details, see if this can be of help.

Comment: It is likely that your `react-dom` and `react` versions don't match.

Comment: @MasterAM this is in my package.json
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2"

i guess they are the same

Comment: Well,  I cannot reproduce thist. You can see what versions are actually installed via `meteor npm list --depth 0`. I simply cloned the repo, went to the step 2.5 commit, updated Meteor and the package versions (both Meteor's and npm's) and installed babel-runtime.

Comment: Well, I don't know why it happened but I just re-installed same version of meteor and it worked.